# FOSElasticaBundle perform nested queries

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, symfony-2.3, elastica, foselasticabundle

I'm learning to use FOSElasticaBundle, but I can not run a query where there are nested fields.

The purpose is this: to look for a query_string in multiple fields, including fields nested.

My setup is:

```
structure:
    mappings:
        name: { boost: 9, type: string }
        locality:
            type: "nested"
            properties:
                locality: { boost: 8, type: string }
```

For now I run this code:

```
$mainQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Bool();
$searchQuery = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString();
$searchQuery->setParam('query', $query);
$searchQuery->setParam('fields', array(
    'name'
));

$searchNested = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString();
$searchNested->setParam('query', $query);
$searchNested->setParam('fields', array(
    'locality'
));
$nestedQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Nested();
$nestedQuery->setPath('locality');
$nestedQuery->setQuery($searchNested);

$mainQuery->addShould($searchQuery);
$mainQuery->addShould($nestedQuery);

$results = $index->search($mainQuery)->getResults();
```

But returns no result!

How do I create queries with nested fields?

Comment: were you able to solve this? I am having the same exact issue

Comment: I "solved" by changing the type of mapping `nested` to `object` and therefore there is no need to perform a nested query but just a normal query!

Comment: is locality a one to many relationship?

Comment: Yes! Structure -> ManyToOne <- Locality

Comment: can you show me the final query what it looks like.. that would really help